# Null Sets - Measure Theory - Infinity Norm

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to learn measure theory by my own and in one part of the
book I am reading (Measures, Integrals and Martingales by Schilling)
I am having trouble to understand why the following statemente is
valid.

For a given measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and some function
$f$, define the following:

$B =\{c>0:\mu(x:\left|f(x)\right|>c)=0\}$

$  \Vert f \Vert _{\infty}=\inf B $

$A=\{x:\left|f(x)\right|>\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{\infty}\} $

I need to show that A has measure 0.

Here is my attempt:

If $A$ is empty then I am done. So Let $\epsilon=\inf_{x\in A} ( |f(x) |- \Vert f \Vert _{\infty} )$.
My problem is I can't guarantee this $\epsilon>0$. But if I can,
then: $\exists c^{\prime}\in B$ such that $c^{\prime} < \Vert f \Vert _{\infty}+\epsilon$.

It follows that from any $x\in A$:

$
c^{\prime}< \Vert f \Vert _{\infty}+\epsilon\leq \Vert f \Vert _{\infty}+ |f(x) |- \Vert f \Vert _{\infty}= |f(x) |$

If we define the set $C^{\prime}= \{ x: |f(x) |\ge c^{\prime} \} $
then we can conclude that $A\subset C^{\prime}$. Since $c^{\prime}\in B$,
we know that $\mu (C^{\prime} )=0$ and we are done.

My problem is how I define $\epsilon$. I am not sure how to deal
with the case if it is 0, or how can I rule this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee that $\epsilon > 0$. For example, consider on $[0, 1]$ function $f(x) = x$ if $x \in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

But note that $A = \cup_n \left\{x : |f(x)| > \|f\|_\infty + \frac{1}{n}\right\}$. By definition of $\|f\|_\infty$, each $\|f\|_\infty + \frac{1}{n}$ is in $B$, thus $\mu\left(\left\{x : |f(x)| > \|f\|_\infty + \frac{1}{n}\right\}\right) = 0$, thus $A$ is countable union of sets of measure zero - thus has measure zero itself.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped a lot!